# Index-refresh in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, index

Is there any way to identify when a specific index was last rebuilt; unless it is used as a batch maintenance activity?

In SQL Server 2008R2 or in advanced versions.

Comment: MySQL, Oracle, SQL Server, ... ??? Edit your tags and add your RDBMS.

Comment: SQL Server 2008R2 or advanced version

Comment: What does "re-indexed latest" mean? Please edit your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SQL server would not be keeping the information on when was index last rebuild, instead you can refer to change or modification\updation in its stats with help of a DMF [sys.dm_db_stats_properties](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj553546(v=sql.105).aspx)  which was introduced for `SQL Server 2008R2` SP2 and above.

You can read [New Statistics DMF in SQL Server 2008R2 SP2](http://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/erin/new-statistics-dmf-in-sql-server-2008r2-sp2/) to query out the object ID and find its respective rebuild date accordingly.

Additionally, what i use is [Ola's Index maintenance solution](https://ola.hallengren.com/sql-server-index-and-statistics-maintenance.html)  which do the Index Maintenance and keeps the history logged into a table, which can be later queried to find desire results and stats on index modifications.

Comment: Why is this answer with -1?

Comment: @RafaelPiccinelli, Even i thought for once, how can this be down voted. Happy to accept -1 in case i get an explanation from the one downvoting this :D

Answer (score 1):

You can only know when the Statistics were last updated using [STATS_DATE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190330.aspx).

You can use either of these queries:

```
SELECT name, STATS_DATE(object_id, index_id), * 
FROM   sys.indexes 
WHERE  name LIKE 'index name'
```

or

```
SELECT name, STATS_DATE(object_id, index_id), * 
FROM   sys.indexes 
WHERE  OBJECT_ID('schema.table') = object_id
```

When you rebuild an index, it updates its statistics:

> If statistics correspond to an index, the stats_id value in the sys.stats catalog view is the same as the index_id value in the sys.indexes catalog view, and the following query returns the same results as the preceding query. If statistics do not correspond to an index, they are in the sys.stats results but not in the sys.indexes results.